# Can Force Grip rules be applied to an AT-ST?

Tags: star-wars-saga-edition, star-wars

I have a question about the effectiveness of Force Grip on an AT-ST in particular. On normal targets it will restrict them to only one free action next round but this seems to be rather extreme when there is a party of 5 heroes versus an AT-ST.

- What I ruled happened for the benefit of continuity: The AT-ST was slightly crushed by the grip doing damage without the other benefits.
- What the player wanted to happen: The AT-ST reduced to one free action and all other benefits applied. His basis for this was he had to maintain the grip with rolling a 17 or above.

Did I do the right thing in this case, or should I apologize to my player for overly nerfing his ability in this application.

Comment: Size matters not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You did the right thing.

He can force grip the AT-ST and do damage, but he can not get rid of the AT-STs actions.  This is because the AT-ST does not HAVE actions.  Vehicles get actions by the the crew members inside of them.  The Pilot uses his move action to move the vehicle.  The gunner uses his standard action to fire the weapons.  This is detailed on page 169 of the Core Rulebook.

If the player wants to limit the actions of the vehicle, he has to target the crew.  That shouldn't be possible as the player has no line of sight on the target due to the AT-ST giving full/total cover.  Unless he has an ability that can ignore line of sight to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be counted as home rule:

- As we know from the movies, characters lose actions because of suffocation;
- Droids are immune to poison, disease, radiation,
  noncorrosive atmospheric hazards, vacuum, mind-affecting effects,
  stunning effects, and any other effect that works only on living
  targets. So this means they are immune to suffocation
- This power still can be used to damage any droid

It's fine to apply this restriction.

**UPD:**

I've take a look once again on it description and found the following (Star Wars - Saga Edition, p/ 97):

```
Special: You main maintain your concentration on the 
    target **creature** to continue damage it from round to round ...
```

Thus, on the other hand, the target should be a creature. It is pointed clearly in description but mentioned in `special`. And it has the point because `as we remember from movies, target suffers from suffocation`.

Comment: an AT-ST is a vehicle not a droid...(there are pilots, gunners etc on board)

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your answer, and to be honest this was my line of thinking before Xphile posted an answer.